# How to use GitLab function "Create Merge Request" from the bash shell?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, gitlab

I need to create a merge request from a forked GitLab repository into the original repository, while running a bash script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#create-mr)

An example merge request would look like this:

> curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: " -X POST
>   https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/projects/project_id/merge_requests/?target_project_id=id_of_parent_project

Comment: Thank you. The GitLab API documentation (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html) says:

**POST /projects/:id/merge_requests**

Could you please explain how I am supposed to come from this to what you wrote? I am asking since I need to understand the syntax for my particular URL.

Comment: What exactly is unclear

Comment: It said: "projects/:id", you said: "project_id". Also, where did you get this variable name: **target_project_id**?

Comment: The project id can be grabbed from the API too, using the projects endpoint. The variable `target_project_name` is an attribute in the API docs listed above.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I got it: it is something like:
    curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXX" -X POST
    "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/projects/
    12345merge_requests?source_branch=XXXXXX&
    target_branch=XXXXXX&title=Test&target_project_id=12356"
Sorry about multiple attempts to format properly.