# Gitlab - How to list all merge requests for a branch from a bash shell?

Tags: gitlab-api

I have a project with many branches and I would like to list all merge requests from a specific branch from the console.

I found the  [merge requests API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-merge-requests) and I also found that I need an HTTP request to do it from this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228561/how-to-use-gitlab-function-create-merge-request-from-the-bash-shell) like this:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXX" -X GET "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/projects/project_name/merge_requests?source_branch=XXXXXX"
```

But I haven't figured out yet how. The response is this:

```
{"message":"404 Project Not Found"}
```

Although the name of the project is correct.

Answer (score 1):

project_name in your example should actually be fully namespaced project name or project ID.

eg: If your project called myproject is under a group called mygroup, the api call would be:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXX" -X GET "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/projects/mygroup%2Fmyproject/merge_requests?source_branch=XXXXXX"
```

If you want to use project ID instead, you can get it at `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/[project path URL encoded]`

Ref:
[HOW to check id of project in gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349236/how-to-check-id-of-project-in-gitlab)